# Fail to connect to CloudMQTT

Tags: c#, mqtt

I have a CloudMQTT Server and I want to connect to it from C# with a client
Using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt

I managed to create a client but it doesn't connect to the server.

```
_client = new MqttClient("m24.cloudmqtt.com",10307,true,null,null,MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_0);

_client.Connect("id", "someUsername", "somePassword");
```

This is the Exception i get

```
Exception thrown: 'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException' in M2Mqtt.Net.dll
```

Comment: What happens when you use `MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2`?

Comment: it's the same result

Comment: Works for us. My suggestion is to use a open-source client like mosquitto first to get it working. Once you have it working, it is far easier to experiment with your client.